# What is the intuitive reason for a function to be continous but not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, intuition

I was just wondering if the following is the right idea for the function to be continuous, but is not differentiable. So, intuitively the function is continuous whenever if we get close to a point a, then f(x) gets close to f(a). If a function is differentiable at a, then we can calculate the tangent line at a. So in order to stop a function from being differentiable at a. We just have to have a function which is continuous whose tangent line oscillate really rapidly to stop it from being differentiable. Is that the right idea ?

Comment: Does your reason apply to $f(x)=|x|$?

Comment: I think @Lord wants to add to your good idea, not replace it.

Comment: It's not necessary to oscillate, it can just be different coming from the left compared to from the right.  E.g. $f(x)=|x|$ as somebody else has mentioned.

Comment: An important family of examples is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x\leq0 \\ x^{\alpha} & x>0\end{cases}$$ for $\alpha>0$. Consider what happens at the breakpoint $x=0$. For the tangent line to exist there, we need the right side of the graph to link up with the negative $x$ axis sufficiently smoothly. This works only if $\alpha>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The function is not differentiable at $a$ when there is *no* tangent line to the graph at the point $\bigl(a,f(a)\bigr)$. The most typical reason for non-existence of a tangent there is when there is a corner at that point. This has nothing to do with oscillations.

However, the oscillation phenomenon also occurs. That's what happens with the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x\sin\left(\frac1x\right)&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0.\end{cases}\end{array}$$It is not differentiable at $0$, although it is continuous there, because the quotiente$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$keeps oscilatting between $1$ and $-1$ as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: But @Jose it seems that the OP wants an intuitive idea why there wouldn't be a tangent there given that it is continuous.

Comment: @StephenMeskin I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah exactly @StephenMeskin. I just want to understand more about the intuition.

Comment: @Newbie Did my answer help you to develop your intuition? If it did not, then I will delete it.

Comment: Isn't also possible to be non-differentiable if as the OP says it oscillates? For example $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x\ne 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$

Comment: @StephenMeskin Again, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah @JoséCarlosSantos it is quite helpful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @José Carlos Santos pointed out. A function is not differentiable at $a$ when there is no tangent line to the graph at the point $(a,f(a))$. An example of this is $f(x)=|x|$ as you can see the problem at $0$ in this graph:
[image: graph $f(x)=|x|$]

Weierstrass later combined this idea with fractals, to produce his monster, a function which is continuous everywhere but nowhere differentiable. For more
see [Weierstrass Monster Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

Comment: I see that is cool thank you for the information. I didn't know about the Weierstrass Monster function. Pretty cool.